# How can I populate textbox through VBA in MS Access?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2003

I have a table RR_info which hold following fields RR_ID, HR_ID, No_of_Beds, Room_Category. Now i want that through VBA code with Form_load event I should populate textboxes for all these table fields. For this I wrote a query which get certain records according to hotel_id as a criteria but code is not working.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim SQL As String
Dim db As Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

SQL = "select * from RR_info where hr_id = " & Forms![hhrrr]![List38] & ";"
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(SQL)

Me.RR_ID.Text = rs!RR_ID
Me.HR_ID.Text = rs!HR_ID
Me.Room_No.Text = rs![Room No]
Me.No_of_Beds.text = rs!No_of_Beds
Me.Room_Category.text = rs!Room_Category

Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

[image]

This is the Picture of Table in which I want to add table data according to criteria through VBA.

Comment: Yeah at me.rr_id.text=rs!rr_id and beyond

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `.Text` property is only available for the control which currently has focus.  When you attempt to reference `.Text` on any other control, you will trigger an error.  The `.Value` property is available whether or not the control has focus.

To be safe, change them all to `.Value`.

```vb
Me.RR_ID.Value = rs!RR_ID
Me.HR_ID.Value = rs!HR_ID
Me.Room_No.Value = rs![Room No]
Me.No_of_Beds.Value = rs!No_of_Beds
Me.Room_Category.Value = rs!Room_Category
```